# Spark Streaming Job starts reading from beginning instead of where it stopped consuming

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use Dataproc on Google Cloud Platform for my Spark Streaming jobs.

I use Kafka as my source and try to write it to MongoDB. Its working fine, but after the job fails it starts to read the messages from my Kafka topic from the beginning instead of from where it stopped.

Here is my config for reading from Kafka:

```
  clickstreamTestDf = (
  spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", confluentBootstrapServers)
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(confluentApiKey, confluentSecret))
  .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
  .option("subscribe", "customer_experience")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()
)
```

And here is my write stream code:

```
finished_df.writeStream \
    .format("mongodb")\
    .option("spark.mongodb.connection.uri", connectionString) \
    .option("spark.mongodb.database", "Company-Environment") \
    .option("spark.mongodb.collection", "customer_experience") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "gs://firstsparktest_1/checkpointCustExp") \
    .option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

1. Do I need to set startingOffsets to latest? I tried but it still didn't read from where it stopped.
2. Can I use checkpointLocation like this? Is it okay to use a directory in google storage?
3. I want to run the streaming job, stop it, delete the Dataproc cluster and then create a new one the next day and continue reading from where it left off. Is that possible and how?

Really need some help here!

Comment: Perhaps you can try specifying `kafka.group.id` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html). Without it, each query runs under newly generated consumer group and hence have no offsets associated with it.

Comment: Yes, GCS is a fine place for checkpoints

Comment: @mazaneicha just giving me a warning that I should use it but I don't think it working, still getting duplicate entries in my database.

Comment: When you start your Spark app now, do you see consumer lag for the topic `customer_experience` decreasing? https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/monitoring/monitor-lag.html

Comment: @mazaneicha I can see it in "Consumers" (but twice the name, seems like at restart it just created another Kafka.group.id for that) but not in Consumer lag

Comment: Kafka stores last committed offsets per consumer group per topic-partition. If your app starts to read a topic from beginning each time, then either your consumer group changes with each run, or application fails to commit the offsets (due to a failure, for example).

Comment: @mazaneicha I'm just a little bit confused because some information I found said I shouldn't set Kafka.group.id and spark doesn't commit offsets back to Kafka because its all managed by the checkpointLocation

Comment: Spark can do both, last I checked. The checkpoints are mainly intended to be used to get "exactly once processing".  The documentation doesn't explicitly say not to set a group id, it only says that it should not duplicate an existing consumer group, which is not a problem specific to Spark. Otherwise, it'll create a random one, and any Kafka consumer with a brand new group is expected to reset their offsets to where you've defined; in this case, the beginning of the topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer Okay thank you, I will try again with group id and check my results!

Comment: @OneCricketeer So if I define a group.id and set startingOffset to earliest it will start from the beginning right? And if it stopped/failed and I use the same group.id again it will continue where it left, even tough startingOffsets is set to earliest?

Comment: @hmh0402 That's typically how consumer groups work, yes.